# How to get my docker image to keep running?

Tags: r, macos, docker, terminal

I am trying to run a docker image, but it will not stay running.

```
cd /Users/emma/Documents/examples/question-1 .
docker build -t q1-model:v1 .
docker run \
     -v $(pwd)/synthetic_data:/data:ro \
     -v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw \
     -v $(pwd)/scratch:/scratch:rw \
     awesome-covid19-q1-model:v1 R /app/model-1.r
```

On docker desktop, I can see the image, but it says it has been "exited," and when I try to click the "start" arrow to run it, it only runs for a second and then goes back to "exited."

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Does that `R` command run forever, or does it compute some model and then exit?

Comment: It is difficult to debug your scenario without knowing the run command you are passing to the container (what is `/app/model-1.r`, is it something that is expected to run in a few seconds?), or how the image is built. You can try starting the container with a terminal to see if everything is built properly and the volumes are mounted as expected, with `docker run -it q1-model:v1 /bin/bash` and then inspect the container.

Comment: Additionally, should the image names `q1-model` and `awesome-covid19-q1-model` not be the same?

Comment: Thank you; to be honest, this is a little bit over my head for where I am at with the language, but @zr0gravity7 your command did work

Answer (score 0):

Try appending to the end of your command `&& sleep infinity`.

If your container does not die, it means that your command is running for a couple of seconds and finishing,and after that the container is killed as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try running the container in detached mode by using the -d flag.

Comment: This should not affect the lifecycle of a container.